# How can I download a file to my downloads folder android

Tags: android, android-emulator, download

I want to download a file using android to my sdcard and then see it from my android emulator. I can download a file to

`/mnt/sdcard/myfile.jpg`

I want to see this file from my android emulator.

Or I can download it to my downloads folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this example for downloading and saving the file: http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification.
After you downloaded the file you can see it in the DDMS perspective, at the "file explorer" view. There will be an "sdcard" folder. Please also be sure that you set the size of the emulator's SD card when you created the emulator.

Comment: I want to see my downloaded file from my android emulator. I can download and save to sdcard.

Comment: You can install a file manager on your emulator. For example you can download the .apk file of the OI File manager from here (http://openintents.org/en/filemanager). Then you can install it on your emulator with the "adb install" command. I tried it and it works. Please let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: My command prompt said 'adb' is not recognized as an in operable program or batch file.

Comment: Set your current directory to your "platform-tools" folder: YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH\platform-tools\. Then the adb command should be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood what you need is a File Browser on your emulator .

Here's a random [File Browser](http://code.google.com/p/mandfilebrowser/downloads/detail?name=MAndFileBrowser.apk) I found ( Google search ) .

Download the apk and install it with adb :

```
adb install MAndFileBrowser.apk
```

Comment: My command prompt said `'adb' is not recognized as an in
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Pritom adb is a tool provided by the android sdk, it should be located in the platform-tool folder you should be able to run it from there . If you are having difficulty with adb , I suggest you open the download link from the emulator using the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

U can save downloaded file to specific folder also by creating folder in external Storage.and when the download gets complete u can display it(i.e if u r downloading image u can show in imageview)

Comment: I want to see my downloaded file from my android emulator. I can download and save to sdcard.

Comment: which file r u talking abt.i told u if u r downloading image then set it as imageview

Comment: that is not matter, i can show downloaded file in imageview, but i want it to save downloads folder and can browser from emulator, is this possible or not?